# Line chart representation of List containing double values

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, data-visualization, linechart

I have Lists of values containing double type numbers and each of this lists contains about 5000 values. Each of this lists has been collected from a microcontroller within 60 seconds.
I want to create a line chart to show the variance of this values. I tried to use the Spline Chart in Flutter but I cannot manage to make it read values from a list as its throwing this error:

> The return type 'List?' isn't a 'num?', as required by the closure's context.

and here is the code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<ChartData> chartData = [
      ChartData(10, [5.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(20, [2.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(30, [1.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(40, [0.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(50, [0.5,3.6]),
      ChartData(60, [0.5,2.6]),
      ChartData(70, [0.5,1.6]),
      ChartData(80, [0.5,0.63]),
      ChartData(90, [0.5,0.126]),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(
                    series: <ChartSeries>[
                      // Renders spline chart
                      SplineSeries<ChartData, int>(
                          dataSource: chartData,
                          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y
                      )
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final int x;
  final List? y;
}
```

I tried to create a list that has few values and called some elements from each list to the chart. It looked like this:

```
List x =[1.0,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.9,1.8,1.9,2.9,3.9,1.9,1.8,1.4];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<ChartData> chartData = [
      ChartData(10, x[1]),
      ChartData(20, x[2]),
      ChartData(30, x[0]),
      ChartData(40, x[4]),
      ChartData(50, x[5]),
      ChartData(60, x[6]),
      ChartData(70, x[7]),
      ChartData(80, x[8]),
      ChartData(90, x[9]),
    ];
```

And this worked for me but Can I make it so I can call all the elemnts from the list to the chart.
Do you have any suggestion on how to make this thing happens.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y` in `ChartData` is List. And you try to assign it to `num?`

```
yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y
```

If the length of `y` is not fixed, you can use this function to generate `SplineSeries`

```
 List<SplineSeries> generateSplineSeries(List<ChartData> chartData){
    List<SplineSeries> splines = [];
    for(int i=0; i<chartData.first.y!.length; i++){
      splines.add( SplineSeries<ChartData, int>(
        dataSource: chartData,
        xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
        yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y![i],
      ));
    }
    return splines;
  }
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<ChartData> chartData = [
      ChartData(10, [5.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(20, [2.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(30, [1.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(40, [0.5,0.6]),
      ChartData(50, [0.5,3.6]),
      ChartData(60, [0.5,2.6]),
      ChartData(70, [0.5,1.6]),
      ChartData(80, [0.5,0.63]),
      ChartData(90, [0.5,0.126]),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(
                    series: generateSplineSeries(chartData),
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This doesnt really solve my problem here. What you did is similar to what I showed in the question in the second part : final List<ChartData> chartData = [
      ChartData(10, x[1]),
      ChartData(20, x[2]),
      ChartData(30, x[0]),
      ChartData(40, x[4]),
      ChartData(50, x[5]),
      ChartData(60, x[6]),
      ChartData(70, x[7]),
      ChartData(80, x[8]),
      ChartData(90, x[9]),
    ];
But What I want to do is to take all the elements from the big list which I mentioned that it has 5000 values and map it in the chart.

Comment: So Lets say that 2 X points between 10 and 20, I want the line to be going up and down based on the first 100 values for example

Comment: Please let me know if I am not explaining this properly and I will try my best to make it clearer

Comment: Did you mean `y` has 5000 values?

Comment: Yes y is gonna be a list with 5000 values and I want to map all those values without doing it manually like ChartData(40, x[4]),
      ChartData(50, x[5]),
      ChartData(60, x[6]), ...etc

Comment: Is it even possible or its better if I get an average of each 100 values to make it smaller

Comment: You can use `generateSplineSeries` which I added on my edit instead of creating it manually.

Comment: You can calculate the average of 100 values ​​before adding them to `ChartData`.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I am almost there. Just one question, in this line: "splines.add( SplineSeries<ChartData2, int>(" Why is it CharData2 not CharData. When I tried it as CharData, It did work but It didnt drow the line

Comment: I will add my new code as an answer so you can see it

Comment: Sorry, I've edited to `ChartData`. You can

Comment: What about the line not being draw, Could you please just at look at the code I posted as an answer and tell me what is wrong there

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List x =[10.0,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.9,1.8,1.9,2.9,3.9,1.9,1.8,1.4];
    final List<ChartData> chartData = [
      ChartData(60,x),

    ];
    List<SplineSeries> generateSplineSeries(List<ChartData> chartData){
      List<SplineSeries> splines = [];
      for(int i=0; i<chartData.first.y!.length; i++){
        splines.add( SplineSeries<ChartData, int>(
          dataSource: chartData,
          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y![i],
        ));
      }
      return splines;
    }
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(
                    series: generateSplineSeries(chartData),
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final int x;
  final List? y;
}
```